# What is the javascript equivalent of the MongoDb sort function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like to create a Javascript function that works like the MongoDb sort function, for sorting object arrays. I am having trouble finding any documentation on how the MongoDB sort function works.

Example of a mongodb query and sort:

```
documentService.findAll().sort ({name: 1, height: -1})
```

Comment: Have you googled "javascript sort"?

Comment: I understand how "javascript sort" works. But I am interested in being able to replicate the MongoDb sort exactly.

Comment: Here you go, have fun: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/sorter/sorter.cpp

Answer (score 3):

Referencing [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398944/1541563) to [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/1541563), a fairly compact implementation could look something like this:

```js
const sortBy = fn => (a, b) => -(fn(a) < fn(b)) || +(fn(a) > fn(b))
const sort = o => Object.entries(o)
  .map(([k, sign]) => [sortBy(({ [k]: v }) => v), sign])
  .map(([f, sign]) => (a, b) => f(a, b) * sign)
  .reduce((f, g) => (a, b) => f(a, b) || g(a, b))

const mySort = sort({ name: 1, height: -1 })
const data = [{ name: 'b', height: 5 }, { name: 'a', height: 6 }, { name: 'a', height: 4 }, { name: 'b', height: 3 }]

console.log(data.sort(mySort))
```